# Tableau Desktop installation hangs on OS/X with 'Verifying "Tableau Desktop.pkg"'

Tags: tableau-api

I have downloaded the `Tableau Desktop` app. The behavior of the installation attempt is that we first see a `Verifying "Tableau Desktop.pkg"` dialog:

[image]
This completes successfully and then a `Finder` window with a single `Tableau Desktop.pkg` icon is presented. Double clicking on the icon results in the *same* `Verifying "Tableau Desktop.pkg"` dialog - but *this* time it does not even start: just hangs forever:

[image]

Installation has been attempted several ways:

- clicking on the downloaded file
- opening the directory in finder, right clicking and selecting `Open`
- opening the directory in finder, right clicking and selecting `Open with` and selecting `Installer.app`

All of these approaches have the same result: the following dialog that hangs forever (I even left it overnight!)

In addition I tried:

- Disabling the `OS/X Gatekeeper` - which is not a great idea for security purposes. But even that did not resolve the issue.
- Re-downloading the app  - to give it a chance that the download were corrupted

After re-downloading the app The files look like this:

```
 $ls -lrta Tableau*
 -rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  463817947 May 19 19:58 TableauDesktop-10-2-2.dmg
 -rw-r--r--@ 1 steve  staff  463817947 May 19 21:44 TableauDesktop-10-2-2 (1).dmg
```

- I also tried the `Tableau Public`: same behavior.

So that is at least six different ways opening this app has been attempted.

I am on `El Capitan`.

Comment: FWIW, I have installed on a Mac OS/X many times, and never had this behavior. So it may be something specific to your configuration. I'm sure the vendor would appreciate it if you reported the problem and details to their support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found an approach that worked: going into `System Recovery` mode and doing `csrutil disable`.  The installation then proceeded.

That is an ***extreme*** measure .. but nothing else sufficed.